# Xtend: Removing Active Annotation during code generation

Tags: java, xtend

I've created an active annotation @Module, but I don't want the generated Java class to be annotated with @Module.

When I try to remove the annotation during the transformation phase, it instead comments out the annotation (which would be fine), but leaves the import in.

Code that is supposed to remove the annotation:

```
override doTransform(MutableClassDeclaration annotatedClass, extension TransformationContext context) {
    annotatedClass.removeAnnotation(annotatedClass.annotations.findFirst[annotationTypeDeclaration == Module.newTypeReference.type])
}
```

Generated class:

```
import my.package.Module;

/* @Module */@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class MyClass {}
```

Xtend version: 2.11

xbase lib gwt version: 2.9.2

Xtend eclipse plugin version: 2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to Java 8 and now the annotation removal code works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with `Module.findTypeGlobally` instead of `Module.newTypeReference.type`?

Comment: Same result. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Is there a way to share a reproducible example?